# Cannot see other pages when using TabbePage

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I am working on a Xamarin project and created a TabbedPage (HomePage.xaml) with xmlns set to the project to reference any added content pages.
I am new to Xamarin so not sure what my mistake is here, but I followed an example and it seems like I cannot see any of the content pages I have added to my project.

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TicketStore"
             x:Class="TicketStore.HomePage">
        <local:MainPage/>
        <local:HockeyPage/>
        <local:FootballPage/>
        <local:BasketballPage/>
 </TabbedPage>
```

From the above code only `<local:MainPage/>` can be referenced the other pages are showing up as  errors.
The error in detail is:

```
/Users/stephen/Projects/TicketStore/TicketStore/HomePage.xaml(5,5): Error: XLS0414: The type 'local:HockeyPage' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. (TicketStore) IntelliSense
```

I have looked to find other examples online and don't see anything that I'm doing differently.

Here is the .xaml.cs code for the HomePage content file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TicketStore
{
    public partial class HomePage : TabbedPage
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help here.

Comment: do you have a page with a class name `HockeyPage` in the `TicketStore` namespace?

Comment: Yes I have added all my pages to the app.

Comment: That’s not what I asked.  What is the namespace of the HockeyPage class?

Comment: The namespace for all added pages is TicketStore

Comment: Delete bin, obj folders in project and rebuild the solution, If still issue is not resolved. Delete and recreate the content pages and try it. if the two solutions are not worked try to create project with Tabbed Page template.

Comment: I updated my macbook and a restart later things seem to work with no changes made by me.  Weird but the issue is gone.  Thanks for all the feedback.